# How to restore a MySQL table with arrays?

Tags: php, mysql

I accidently made a terrible mistake and now my whole table is gone. Fortunately this was the first table which I have ever exported, so I have a back-up. But I have exported it as a .php and it's exported in this way:

```
$vocabulary = array(
  array('Language' => 'Gotisch','Nederlands' => 'Gotisch','German' => 'Gotisch','English' => 'Gothic','article' => '','id' => '0','type' => '','French' => ''),
  array('Language' => 'aug´','Nederlands' => 'oog','German' => 'Auge','English' => 'eye','article' => ' ','id' => '0','type' => '','French' => ''))
```

Is there a way in which I can re-insert it in MySQL? Because it doesn't seem to be a .CSV or .XML, in other words, can I convert it in one of those file-types?

Comment: It wouldn't be difficult to write a short PHP script to insert the data working directly from this.

Comment: Yes, I would like to restore them with phpMyAdmin. But where can I find how to do that? I pressed 'Repair Table', but it did nothing. :S

Comment: @Blogger You'll need to create an INSERT statement from this php array. What is the table structure?

Comment: Php has some csv functions. See fputcsv() and other functions to build your own convert script.

Comment: The table structure contains the values: 'language','Nederlands','German','English','article','id','type','French'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just loop through it and query everything?

```
<?php
$vocabulary = array(
  array('Language' => 'Gotisch','Nederlands' => 'Gotisch','German' => 'Gotisch','English' => 'Gothic','article' => '','id' => '0','type' => '','French' => ''),
  array('Language' => 'aug´','Nederlands' => 'oog','German' => 'Auge','English' => 'eye','article' => ' ','id' => '0','type' => '','French' => ''));

foreach($vocabulary as $word) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (Language, Nederlands, German, English, article, id, type, French) VALUES ('" . $word['Language'] . "', '". $word['Nederlands'] . "', '" . $word['German'] . "', '" . $word['English'] . "', '" . $word['article'] . "', '". $word['id'] . "', '" . $word['type'] . "', '" . $word['French'] . "')";
    //query $sql here. also change tbl to your table name
}

?>
```

Comment: Yay! It worked :D Thank you, this was a recent export so it aren't that much words which I am missing now.

Comment: Ok, I 'm still having problems with symbols imported wrongly. But I can solve this by truncating the table and inserting the symbols replaced by the right ones.

Comment: I have restored a part of them, but some are still wrong and it's hard to find the right symbols, help would be appreciated: í» , º½ , íµ  , they are displayed like in these examples: aí­kklesjíµ, aí­waggáº½ljíµ    I need the right symbols in the array to insert them correct in MySQL

Comment: @Blogger Why don't you have the right symbols in the array? Show me an example from your array.

Comment: They don't appear randomly in the sense of random, because there's a pattern, I have replaced a few of these characters with the right symbol and they make all the words with the same characters correct. The string I 'm adding to the table is your code, but my array which was exported from mySQL for some reason exported all the special symbols in the wrong way. I could use some special function, but replacing the symbols seems more practical, I just need a list with the right symbols and don't know where to find it.

Comment: @Blogger Add to your question an example of the symbols and I'll add a code to fix it.

Comment: Example of array:    array('Language' => 'aí­waggáº½ljíµ','Nederlands' => 'evangelie','German' => 'Evangelium,Frohe Botschaft','English' => 'evangel,gospel,good tidings','article' => ' ','id' => '0','type' => '','French' => ''),

Comment: @Blogger What is `aí­waggáº½ljíµ` supposed to be?

Comment: That is the problem. Of some symbols I can't find anymore what they were supposed to be. So I 'm looking for a list of these special characters.

Comment: Let me try html_entities

Comment: Ok, I have replaced everything in the array without using some special function. I think about everything is replaced now.

Comment: @Blogger Okay good because I've been looking around and I have no idea why that happens. Maybe some encoding issues.

Answer (score 1):

This will create a CSV file for you.

```
<?php
$vocabulary = array(
    array('Language' => 'Gotisch','Nederlands' => 'Gotisch','German' => 'Gotisch','English' => 'Gothic','article' => '','id' => '0','type' => '','French' => ''),
    array('Language' => 'aug´','Nederlands' => 'oog','German' => 'Auge','English' => 'eye','article' => ' ','id' => '0','type' => '','French' => ''));

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
foreach($vocabulary as $row)
{
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: I will try your solution later, the one of Shahar worked too, but your one may be good too to know for the future.